# Getting error for Flutter http.get('url') parameter It's not accepting Url String

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-http

I'm trying to fetch all json data which https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Cocktail api returns, to use it in my flutter app

```
var api="https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Cocktail";
var res=await http.get(api);
drinks= jsonDecode(res.body)["drinks"];
```

but it gives red underline under api parameter in http.get(api) function call that  "argument of type string cannot be converted to URI"
How to Resolve this? I even tried  using
`res=await http.get(Uri.https('www.thecocktaildb.com','/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Cocktail'));`

but got error "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to [http://127.0.0.1:63573"/_fprblq_tiY=/"](http://127.0.0.1:63573%22/_fprblq_tiY=/%22)

Comment: good solution thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Uri.https()`, try using `Uri.parse()`

Comment: It Throws an error even for res=await http.get(Uri.parse(api)); "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:64971/ypwDk3yQ650=/"

Comment: Seems like it's not a code issue at all! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933251/flutter-occurs-error-connecting-to-the-service-protocol-httpexception-erro

Comment: yes sir it wasn't code issue, resolved it with help of answers present here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933251/flutter-occurs-error-connecting-to-the-service-protocol-httpexception-erro

Comment: Its strange but it worked after 1)I disconnected my laptop from wifi 2)Unplugged usb cable and phone from laptop again connected laptop to wifi 3)connecting phone to laptop and running app

Comment: but all this happened after passing Uri.Parse(api) to http.get(Uri.Parse(api)) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add :
`http: ^0.13.4` to your `pubspec.yaml` , it will provide you with some simple methods to access apis.
You cannot add `?` directly because it will convert to `3%F` I believe, same for other special characters.

```
var url = 'thecocktaildb.com';
var urlExtension = '/api/json/v1/1/filter.php';
final Map<String, String> queryParameters = <String, String>{
  'c': 'Cocktail',
};
final api = Uri.https(url, urlExtension, queryParameters);

//It should be something like this, now you can get
//the api response the way you were doing:

var res=await http.get(api);
drinks= jsonDecode(res.body)["drinks"];
```